# Does Google Chrome caches the content/background scripts of an extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm always wondering if the content scripts and background scripts are cached by the browser.

We have a client and whenever we send him a copy of the extension for testing, it behaves differently on his part even though we are using the same version of Chrome browser.

Comment: Yes, a persistent background script and content scripts are loaded on the start of browser profile or when the extension is reloaded explicitly on chrome://extensions page, or when the extension is updated via webstore.

Comment: Hi do you have any sources or point which part in the documentation I can find this information?

Comment: You can easily confirm it yourself, I think it shouldn't take more than a minute or two.

Comment: I  mean can you give a link to the part of the documentation where this information was mentioned?

Comment: I also wanted to add the we are using a local copy of the extension where we use the `Load Unpacked` option in the extensions page to load it. This extension hasn't been published into the webstore yet.

Comment: Well, you need to instruct the users to reload it on chrome://extensions page or implement a self-reload button in your UI that will invoke chrome.runtime.reload(). They will also have to refresh the affected web pages if you don't implement reinjection of content scripts in that button's code.

Comment: Okay got that. Can you convert your response into an answer so I can mark it as the accepted answer later if this solved our issue? Thanks.